# What is the steady state response of a system of two exponentials to sinusoidal excitation?

Tags: linear-systems

What is the two exponential steady state response?

Here is an example solution for sinusoidal excitation of a system having a single exponential response to a impulse excitation:

**Example:**

Excitation: impulse: $L(t) = \delta(t)$

Impulse response of system: $I(t) = I_o e^{-t/\lambda}$

Excitation:  sinusoid: $L(t) = a + b \sin(\omega t)$

Sinusoid response of system:  $I(t) = I_o \lambda \left(a + \frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + (\omega \lambda)^2}} \cos(\omega t - θ)\right)$

$\tan(\theta) = \omega \lambda$

**Question:**  What is a similar solution for a system that has a double exponential impulse response?

Excitation: impulse: $L(t) = \delta(t)$

Impulse response of system: $I(t) = I_{o1} e^{-t/\lambda_1} + I_{o2} e^{-t/\lambda_2}$

Excitation:  sinusoid: $L(t) = a + b \sin(\omega t)$

Sinusoid response of system: ????

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Please format your equations

Comment: Anyway you just have to take the convolution among the impulse response and the input signal

Comment: Since you have the solution for a single exponential already given, you can easily exploit the linearity of the system: The output is the sum of the responses of the two exponentials.

Comment: For the sake of correctness, "double exponential" is not what you have written. It is something like $a^{b^{c}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The system with impulse response:
$$I(t)=I_1e^{-t/\lambda_1}+I_2e^{-t/\lambda_2}$$

with Laplace Transform:
$$I(s)=I_1\frac{1}{s+1/\lambda_1}+I_2\frac{1}{s+1/\lambda_2}$$

and the input:
$$L(t)=a+bsin(\omega)$$

with Laplace Transform:
$$L(s)=\frac{a}{s}+\frac{bw}{s^2+w^2}$$

will obtain the following output, in Laplace Domain:
$$IL(s)=I(s)L(s)=(I_1\frac{1}{s+1/\lambda_1}+I_2\frac{1}{s+1/\lambda_2}) (\frac{a}{s}+\frac{bw}{s^2+w^2})$$

with this very simple Inverse Laplace Transform, as the final solution:
$$IL(t)=
-\frac{I_1 \lambda_1 e^{-t/\lambda_1} (a \lambda_1^2 w^2 + a - b \lambda_1 w)}{\lambda_1^2 w^2 + 1} 
- \frac{I_2 \lambda_2 e^{-t/\lambda_2} (a \lambda_2^2 w^2 + a - b \lambda_2 w)}{\lambda_2^2 w^2 + 1} 
+ a I_1 \lambda_1 + a I_2 \lambda_2 
+ \frac{\{b (sin(t w) (I_1 (\lambda_1 \lambda_2^2 w^2 + \lambda_1) + I_2 \lambda_2 (\lambda_1^2 w^2 + 1))
- w cos(t w) (I_1 \lambda_1^2 (\lambda_2^2 w^2 + 1) + I_2 \lambda_2^2 (\lambda_1^2 w^2 + 1)))\}}{(\lambda_1^2 w^2 + 1) (\lambda_2^2 w^2 + 1)}$$

As you can see, this kind of symbolisms can be readily solved in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) through [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverselaplacetransform((c%2F(s%2B1%2Fm)%2Bd%2F(s%2B1%2Fn))*(a%2Fs%2Bbw%2F(s%5E2%2Bw%5E2)))):

```
inverselaplacetransform((c/(s+1/m)+d/(s+1/n))*(a/s+bw/(s^2+w^2)))
```